# (Done) Reopen: Is it ok for me to spend all day working for a prospective employer as part of the interview process

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116219/) has been closed as primarily opinion based. It's asking for advice on how to set professional boundaries, which I fail to see how it falls under *bad subjective* or *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: It was not asking for advice. It was asking on what is the way or norm of doing something like that. The question generally ask on what is the process.

Comment: I agree the question should be reopened. It has two reopen votes now. [Let me see if I can find some more voters at the water cooler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45792010#45792010). :)

Comment: @MaskedMan - You have mod powers.  If you think it should be reopened then use them.  That is why you were elected was to take moderator action where it is appropriate.

Comment: @IDrink Being elected a moderator doesn't mean I have given up my regular membership of the community. Moderators do not override the community. The appropriate moderator action here was to obtain community feedback.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Key words being "where it is appropriate". Moderators are supposed to be exception handlers. There's no reason why this question couldn't be handled by the community, as it has been.

Comment: *Moderators are supposed **Only** to be  exception handlers* - Citation needed. (Insertion of explicit only mine but implied in original statement)

Comment: Moderators are allowed to use our powers (we have them, after all), but should be restrained.  If I think it's *obvious* that something should be closed/reopened/deleted/undeleted, I'll do it -- especially close/delete because it reduces the damage.  I'll reopen something if the OP has made a real effort, I'm satisfied, and the community is just nit-picking.  But *usually* we want the community to do these things.

Comment: @Lilienthal - Reopening questions that were closed inappropriately seems to fall in to the middle of where appropriate.

Comment: For the record **I'm happy with how this instance was handled**, and would've been happy if it didn't get reopened. 1) I drew attention to a question, 2) someone (who happened to be a mod) boosted it (although he didn't vote himself), 3) the question got reopened. @IDrinkandIKnowThings Correct me if I'm wrong, you seem to suggest that mods should reopen questions willy-nilly. Is this the case, and if so, could you please add Meta post so we can discuss it properly?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the title "*Is it ok for me to spend all day working for a prospective employer as part of the interview process*" - Sure, **if you want to**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been reopened.